# for loop in R to calculate mean from list

Tags: r, for-loop, mean

This [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/291662/for-loop-in-r-to-calculate-mean-from-list) is on cross validated too and I was directed to post here.

I have a list called `d` that contains values in R.

```
> d
$`2017-07-15:10:09:22`
[1] 3.125 4.375 2.500 0.625 5.000 3.750 1.875 1.250

$`2017-07-15:10:10:04`
[1] 0.625 3.750 3.125 1.875 1.250 4.375 2.500 5.000

$`2017-07-15:11:45:45`
[1] 4.375 3.125 3.750 2.500 5.000 1.875 1.250 0.625
```

I am interested in calculating Mean value of these points and save it to a data frame. So, i made a for loop to do this

```
l2 <- length(d)
for(j in 1:6)
{
      df$Mean[j] <- (d[[1]][j] 
            + d[[2]][j] + d[[3]][j])/l2 

}
```

And the length of the list `d` gets bigger every time. I would like to make this `for` loop to calculate the mean on its own. Like this..

```
l2 <- length(d)   
for(j in 1:6)
       {
              df$Mean[j] <- (d[[1]][j] 
                    + d[[2]][j] + d[[3]][j] + d[[4]][j] + ....
               )/l2 

        }
```

how to make loop of this one to do automatically?  Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @F.Maas pointed out correctly, you don't need to loop here.

But if I understood your question correctly, you want the mean of each point over all list elements and not the mean of points *within* each list element.

If my assumption is right, this code should do what you need, and it doesn't even need `lapply`:

```
#create test data and names
d <- lapply(1:3,function(x) runif(6))
names(d) <- sample(LETTERS,length(d))

> d
$V
[1] 0.9369505 0.7825348 0.4549225 0.3807600 0.7169146 0.3608166

$Z
[1] 0.75466094 0.09207062 0.59738221 0.33558258 0.79022386 0.98266940

$G
[1] 0.3441581 0.6696056 0.5544217 0.7422718 0.6682706 0.7989314


#calculate means

res <- colMeans(do.call(rbind,d))
```

Now you have the means for each point. You can add them to an existing `data.frame` or make a new one.

```
#put into df

df <- data.frame(means=res)

#output

> df
      means
1 0.6785898
2 0.5147370
3 0.5355755
4 0.4862048
5 0.7251363
6 0.7141391
```

So the only thing you need is `colMeans(do.call(rbind,d))`, which collapses your list into a matrix with each column representing a point. After that I can just use `colMeans` to calculate the mean.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for (Example Code):

```
> set.seed(1)
> data<-list(a=rnorm(10),b=rnorm(10),c=rnorm(10),d=rnorm(10))
> data_mean<-rep(0,10)
> data
$a
 [1] -0.6264538  0.1836433 -0.8356286  1.5952808  0.3295078 -0.8204684  0.4874291  0.7383247  0.5757814
[10] -0.3053884

$b
 [1]  1.51178117  0.38984324 -0.62124058 -2.21469989  1.12493092 -0.04493361 -0.01619026  0.94383621
 [9]  0.82122120  0.59390132

$c
 [1]  0.91897737  0.78213630  0.07456498 -1.98935170  0.61982575 -0.05612874 -0.15579551 -1.47075238
 [9] -0.47815006  0.41794156

$d
 [1]  1.35867955 -0.10278773  0.38767161 -0.05380504 -1.37705956 -0.41499456 -0.39428995 -0.05931340
 [9]  1.10002537  0.76317575

> lapply(data,"[",n=4) #access the 4th entry of every list part - only needs to be transformed to numeric vector
$a
[1] 1.595281

$b
[1] -2.2147

$c
[1] -1.989352

$d
[1] -0.05380504

> for(i in 1:length(data[[1]]))(
+   data_mean[i]<-mean(as.numeric(lapply(data,"[",n=i)))
+ )
> data_mean
 [1]  0.79074607  0.31320878 -0.24865815 -0.66564396  0.17430122 -0.33413132 -0.01971167  0.03802378
 [9]  0.50471947  0.36740756
```

Basically, you just have to insert `mean(as.numeric(lapply(d,"[",n=j)))` into your `for`-loop.

Comment: You're proposing a nested loop, seems to be a bit of an overkill to me.

Comment: @Val I agree, that your suggestion is more numerically efficient. I just wanted to provide an alternative, in case someone wanted to do this in a `for` loop (for whatever reason).